# Git-Tfs sending the wrong identity to tfs during shelve

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

When I try to shelve my changes from git-tfs using the command `git tfs shelve MY_SHELVE_NAME`, I get the following error:

```
TF14045 The identity {my domain}\{my windows user display name} is not a recognized identity.
```

It looks like git tfs is passing my display name and not my user name. It tried setting the local config value tfs-remote.default.username and tfs-remote.username to my windows user name, but that didn't work. Am I using the wrong config values or is something else wrong?

The output of `git tfs shelve MY_SHELVE_NAME -d`

```
  git command: Starting process: git log --no-color --pretty=medium HEAD
  git command: Starting process: git config --list
  git command time: [00:00:00.1340134] config --list
  git command time: [00:00:00.1700170] log --no-color --pretty=medium HEAD
  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.IdentityNotFoundException: TF14045: The identity DOMAINNAME\Display Name is not a recognized identity. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF14045: The identity DOMAINNAME\Display Name is not a recognized identity.
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ProcessHttpResponse(HttpWebResponse response, Stream responseStream, WebException webException, XmlReader& xmlResponseReader)
     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.ExecWebServiceRequest(HttpWebRequest request, XmlWriter requestXml, String methodName, HttpWebResponse& response)
     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository.QueryShelvesets(String shelvesetName, String ownerName)
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.VsCommon.TfsHelperBase.HasShelveset(String shelvesetName)
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitTfsRemote.HasShelveset(String shelvesetName) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Core\GitTfsRemote.cs:line 432
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Shelve.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Run>b__0(TfsChangesetInfo changeset) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Commands\Shelve.cs:line 49
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.TfsWriter.Write(String refToWrite, Func`2 write) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Core\TfsWriter.cs:line 29
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Shelve.Run(String shelvesetName, String refToShelve) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Commands\Shelve.cs:line 47
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Commands.Shelve.Run(String shelvesetName) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Commands\Shelve.cs:line 42
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Util.GitTfsCommandRunner.Run(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 args) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Util\GitTfsCommandRunner.cs:line 36
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.GitTfs.Main(GitTfsCommand command, IList`1 unparsedArgs) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:line 56
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.GitTfs.Run(IList`1 args) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\GitTfs.cs:line 39
     at Sep.Git.Tfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\work\git-tfs\GitTfs\Program.cs:line 23
  TF14045: The identity DOMAINNAME\Display Name is not a recognized identity.
  TF14045: The identity DOMAINNAME\Display Name is not a recognized identity.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known defect.  If you get the [latest git-tfs code](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs.git) and build it this issue will be fixed.

Here is the bug report comment that is relevant:
https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/issues/81#issuecomment-1979918

**Update**

This was fixed in the latest binary drop [0.12.1](https://github.com/downloads/spraints/git-tfs/GitTfs-0.12.1.zip)

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed that issue.